# Chrome connects to websocket before pressing enter

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, express, socket.io

While making realtime chat with express.js and socket.io I noticed strange behaviour of Chrome browser. When i paste chat address `(http://localhost:8000/)` to address bar it connects to site  instantly, without pressing enter. This does not happens in Firefox. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is because chrome has a preloading feature.  You can turn this off in the settings by going to this URL in chrome:

```
chrome://settings/advanced
```

and uncheck: `Predict network actions to improve page load performance`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But is there any trick to prevent this on server side? When client connects to chat, server notices other clients that new user has connected. But it doesn't notices that client disconnected when tab is closed.